# Determine whether the emails bounced back

Tags: email

We have a website on a shared hosting along with webmails. We were not able to access the mail and the hosting provider gave us to an IP address with a port value. When asked about the email bouncing, he said **"No, all your mails will have come and will be available at this IP".** But, I am bit suspicious about this since there have been no mails for past 8-10 hours.

Is there a way to determine if the emails bounced back or the mail server was down during a particular timespan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to determine if you have emails bouncing is to try it yourself or to have a friend try it.  This assumes you do not have direct access to the server in question (logs, etc).

Comment: The mail is working right now. I am concerned about the past timespan. A particular timespan for which I suspect the server was not working on the hosting provider end

Comment: Unless you have someone telling you that they had emails bouncing, there's nothing you can really prove.  I don't suppose you have access to the system's logs, do you?